# Will the Windows 10 "Search Contract" let me show results in the start menu?

Tags: c#, windows, search, contracts

I'm thinking it would be a neat idea to be able to provide search extensions to the start menu (say, so typing in the start menu also searches articles on a website). Is this what the Windows Ten search contract is for? From their API documentation it sounds as if contracts are for App to App interactions.